# Javascript - For loop vs Linked List vs ES6 Set to find two matching integers

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary-search, singly-linked-list

I have prepared 2 Javascript functions to find matching integer pairs that add up to a sum and returns a boolean.

The first function uses a binary search like that:

```
function find2PairsBySumLog(arr, sum) {
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   for (var x = i + 1; x < arr.length; x++) {
     if (arr[i] + arr[x] == sum) {
       return true;
     }
   }
 }
 return false;
}
```

For the second function I implemented my own singly Linked List, in where I add the complementary integer to the sum and search for the value in the Linked List. If value is found in the Linked List we know there is a match.

```
function find2PairsBySumLin(arr, sum) {
  var complementList = new LinkedList();
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (complementList.find(arr[i])) {
      return true;
    } else {
      complementList.add(sum - arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

When I run both functions I clearly see that the Linked List search executes ~75% faster

```
var arr =  [9,2,4,1,3,2,2,8,1,1,6,1,2,8,7,8,2,9];

console.time('For loop search');
console.log(find2PairsBySumLog(arr, 18));
console.timeEnd(‘For loop search’);

console.time('Linked List search');
console.log(find2PairsBySumLin(arr, 18));
console.timeEnd('Linked List search');

true
For loop search: 4.590ms
true
Linked List search: 0.709ms
```

Here my question: Is the Linked List approach a real linear search? After all I loop through all the nodes, while my outer loop iterates through the initial array.

Here is my LinkedList search function:

```
LinkedList.prototype.find = function(data) {
  var headNode = this.head;
  if(headNode === null) {
    return false;
  }
  while(headNode !== null) {
    if(headNode.data === data) {
      return true;
    } else {
      headNode = headNode.next;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

It was a good idea to go back and have another think of the problem based the comments so far.

Thanks to @nem035 comment on small datasets, I ran another test but this time with **100,000** integers between 1 and 8. I assigned 9 to the first and last position and searched for 18 to make sure the entire array will be searched.

I also included the relatively new ES6 **Set** function for comparison thanks to @Oriol.

Btw @Oriol and @Deepak you are right. The first function is not a binary search but rather a O(n*n) search, which has no logarithmic complexity.

It turns out my Linked List implementation was the slowest of all searches. I ran 10 iterations for each function individually. Here the result:

```
For loop search:       24.36 ms (avg)
Linked List search: 64328.98 ms (avg)
Set search:            35.63 ms (avg)
```

Here the same test for a dataset of **10,000,000** integers:

```
For loop search:       30.78 ms (avg)
Set search:          1557.98 ms (avg)
```

**Summary:**

So it seems the Linked List is really fast for smaller dataset up to ~1,000, while ES6 Set is great for larger datasets.
Nevertheless the **For loop** is the clear winner in all tests.

All 3 methods will scale linearly with the amount of data.

Please note: ES6 Set is not backward compatible with old browsers in case this operation has to be done client side.

Comment: Benchmarking on small input sizes isn't very useful. Try large inputs and many times.

Comment: How exactly did you conclude that a nested loop has logarithmic complexity???

Comment: Instead of ES6 sets you can also try `Object.create(null)` as a hash, or a sparse array.

Comment: How did you manage that **JAVASCRIPT** title? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341916/the-all-caps-title-checker-is-somewhat-faulty?cb=1

Answer (score 2):

Don't use this. Use a set.

```
function find2PairsBySum(arr, sum) {
  var set = new Set();
  for(var num of arr) {
    if (set.has(num)) return true;
    set.add(sum - num);
  }
  return false;
}
```

That's all. Both `add` and `has` are guaranteed to be sublinear (probably constant) in average.

Comment: Of course, remember this may not work with decimals, e.g. `0.3 - 0.1` is not `0.2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize this substantially, by pre-sorting the array and then using a real binary search.

```js
// Find an element in a sorted array.
function includesBinary(arr, elt) {
  if (!arr.length) return false;
    
  const middle = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);

  switch (Math.sign(elt - arr[middle])) {
    case -1: return includesBinary(arr.slice(0, middle - 1), elt);
    case 0:  return true;
    case +1: return includesBinary(arr.slice(middle + 1), elt);
  }
}

// Given an array, pre-sort and return a function to detect pairs adding up to a sum.
function makeFinder(arr) {
  arr = arr.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b);

  return function(sum) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const remaining = sum - arr[i];
      if (remaining < 0) return false;
      if (includesBinary(arr, remaining)) return true;
    }
  return false;
  };
}

// Test data: 100 random elements between 0 and 99.
const arr =  Array.from(Array(100), _ => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
const finder = makeFinder(arr);

console.time('test');
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) finder(100);
console.timeEnd('test');
```

According to this rough benchmark, one lookup into an array of 100 elements costs a few microseconds.

Rewriting `includesBinary` to avoid recursion would probably provide a further performance win.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet @torazaburo. Just ran your code with 100,000 integers ([9,....,9]), which took 3.047ms to complete. Really Good.

Comment: Do you mean an array of 100,000 values of `9`, looking for a sum of `18`?

Comment: In my console, with an array of 100,000 elements all equal to 9, running one million iterations takes 77ms.

Comment: I did 2 more tests - 1. with 10,000,000 integers: '2 for loops': 30.647ms vs 'binary': 133.353ms and the 2. with 100,000,000 integers: '2 for loops': 264.193ms vs 'binary': 'JavaScript heap out of memory'. I know that's a bit extreme though.

Answer (score 0):

first of all find2PairsBySumLog function is not a binary search, it's a kind of brute force method which parses all the elements of array and it's worst case time complexity should be O(n*n), and the second function is a linear search that' why you are getting the second method to run fastly, for the first function i.e. find2PairsBySumLog what you can do is initialize binary HashMap and check for every pair of integers in array kind of like you are doing in the second function probably like

```
bool isPairsPresent(int arr[], int arr_size, int sum)
{
  int i, temp;
  bool binMap[MAX] = {0}; 

   for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
   {
     temp = sum - arr[i];
     if (temp >= 0 && binMap[temp] == 1)
          return true;
     binMap[arr[i]] = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: We are talking about Javascript here Deepak.

Comment: The only reason why I mention Javascript is because there are no inbuilt HashMaps or Hashsets. That's why I implemented my own Linked List. I also don't need to save a key and value but just the value.

Comment: Okay you didn't mention that you don't want to store key value pairs but just for information every javascript object is a hashmap map , do something like  var map = {}; and map[key] = value; and that' all